# Is there a way to order data in PROC FEDSQL?

Tags: sas

Is there a way to order data by a column in PROC FEDSQL? From searching online, PROC FEDSQL does not support an ORDER BY statement or PROC SORT, which is causing me issues. This is because I want to sort data before I aggregate the values by group into a single string, but because they are jumbled up, groups with the same set of values appear to have different values when aggregated, because they are in a different order.

For example, if my data is

```
ID value
1  cat
2  bat
2  cat
3  cat
3  bat
```

then this produces the output

```
ID Agg_value
1  "cat"
2  "bat, cat"
3  "cat, bat"
```

So the aggregated value appears different for groups 2 and 3 even though I want it to be the same.

Comment: What is your FEDSQL code for this? As far as I know there's no `string_agg()` equivalent function. I'm curious how you are able to achieve this.

Comment: I used a data step:
  data casuser.source_agg(rename=(source_agg=source));
 do until(last.id);
 set casuser.input_data;
 by id;
 length source_agg $80.;
  source_agg =catx(', ',source, source_agg);
 end;
drop source;
run;

Answer (score 0):

You were close. You need your by-group to be `id source` rather than just `id`. This will guarantee the data is returned in order by `id` and then `source`.

```
data casuser.source_agg(rename=(source_agg=source));
    do until(last.id);
        set casuser.input_data;
        by id source;
        length source_agg $80.;
        source_agg=catx(', ', source_agg, source);
    end;
    drop source;
run;
```

```
id  source
1   cat
2   bat, cat
3   bat, cat
```